# How to set a layout for a template using Blaze in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am dynamically building some templates and trying to set a layout on an html I generate using Blaze in Meteor, here is what I am currently doing

```
Blaze.toHTML(Blaze.With(data, function() { return Template.my_template; }));
```

This returns html from a template using the data in it. I tried searching in the documentation but I couldn't find it, so is there a way to set a layout for this template ?

I am trying to achieve something like

```
<template name="layout">
    <!-- some styling -->
    {{> yield}}
</template
```

And use that with the generation of the html.

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked out [Iron Router](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router)?

Comment: He's using a `{{> yield}}` so he's already got iron:router

Answer (score 0):

Try [Blaze.render()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_render) or [Blaze.renderWithData()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_renderwithdata) instead.

Set a DOM node in your template:

```
<template name="layout">
<!-- some styling -->
<div id="foo"></div> <!-- this will be used like a yield -->
</template
```

Then in your js:

```
Template.layout.onRendered(function(){
  Blaze.render('otherTemplate',$('#foo')[0]);
});
```